# unwanted height animation on SVG

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I'm making a form and I'm using an SVG to create the effect of a gap in the border so I can move the placeholder text up. Currently, I'm sitting it on the border with absolute positioning and setting then width to 0, then when I need the gap to appear I animate the width to the full width. the issue I'm having is instead of just animating the width the height is animating too which means there's some of the background showing through during the animation creating a weird effect. Here's the CSS:

```css
.cutout {
    top: 6px;
    width: 0;
    height: 5px;
    min-height: 5px;
    max-height: 5px;
    transition: width 0.1s ease
}

...

.field:focus-within .cutout {
    width: 130px;
}
```

and the JSX:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../css/input.css'
import cutout from '../img/cutout.svg';

class Input extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <label className="field body-font">
                <input name={this.props.name} type={this.props.type} autocorrect={this.props.autocorrect} id={this.props.id} required />
                <span className="placeholder" >{this.props.placeholder}</span>
                <img className="cutout" src={cutout} alt="" />
            </label>
        );
    }
}

export default Input;
```

of course, I'm going to make it responsive and make it work for not just when the input is focussed later but I would like to get the animation working first. is there any way to make sure the height is always 5px no matter what

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not very clear without seeing your html, but try writing:

```css
.field:focus-within .cutout {
    width: 130px;
    height: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I added that and nothing, I'll add my HTML